# How can we fetch the shelveset name during Gated check-in and assign it to a variable in tfs build task

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, shelveset, gated-checkin

We have a mapped workspace where each project is having multiple references to other projects. On the same workspace, we perform our whole product build nightly.

When we enable gated check-in for individual projects, its creating a new workspace and trying to build. As the other projects are not mapped as part of gated check-in, its failing to build.

Do we have any way to fetch shelveset created during Gated check-in in the tfs build, so that we can use it to unshelve in our local mapped workspace?

Any help/lead is appreciated.

Comment: Map a workspace containing the required references. If you need to split your application into multiple discrete units that can be built and referenced separately, use NuGet packages.

Comment: Hello, I have updated my answer. Please check whether it can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do we have any way to fetch shelveset created during Gated check-in in the tfs build

You can use the REST API [Shelvesets - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/shelvesets/get?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0).

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/_apis/tfvc/shelvesets?shelvesetId={shelvesetId}&api-version=5.0
```

If you don't know the `shelvesetId` you need, you can use the REST API [Shelvesets - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/shelvesets/list?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) to get all your shelvesets.

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/_apis/tfvc/shelvesets?api-version=5.0
```